# sort multiple columns from using ransack from the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am using the ransack gem to sort a table in my view, but using the sorting feature does not allow me to combine the sorting of two or more columns at the same time. Is it possible to use multiple sorting from the view using ransack?

this is my view:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table class="table">
    <!--<caption>Listado Actualizado...</caption>-->
    <thead>

        <tr>    
          <th scope="col">
            <%= sort_link(@q, :code, 'Código medicamento país') %>
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            <%= sort_link(@q, :reverse_mx_standar, 'Descripción') %>
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            <%= sort_link(@q, :reverse_presentacion, 'Presentación') %>
          </th>
          <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="container_t_drugs_devices">
      <%= render @t_drugs_devices %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= will_paginate @t_drugs_devices %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

my controller:

```
  def index

    @q = TDrugsDevice.Busqueda_general(params).por_pais(session[:pais]).ransack(params[:q])
    @t_drugs_devices = @q.result(distinct: true).paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(params[:por_pagina].to_i)


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
      format.xls 
    end
  end
```

I was googling but what I got was the combination of tables from the controller this way:

```
params[:q][:s] = ['reverse_mx_standar asc', 'code asc']
```

but I don't know how I can save the value of the previous params[:q] so that from the view, the user clicks on a column, keeping the previous column sorted